# How to build OSGi(Equinox) project from command line

Tags: java, osgi, osgi-bundle, equinox

I have an `OSGi(Equinox)` project. And I have all required osgi plugin jars in a directory. Now I want to build my project using command line.

In fact, I have two `OSGi project`, say A and B. A is depending on B and also depending on some other plugins. I want to build A.

Actually project A building in eclipse as I defined a `Target platform` targeting my plugin directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Maven and Tycho. There is a good  [tycho tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTycho/article.html) to help you get started.

Comment: Thanks @Pavel, Thats exactly what is need.